# Django models id issue

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm not able to query a django model.

the model is as follow.

```
class DeviceLevelMapping(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(DeviceDetails)
    level1 = models.ForeignKey('Level1Detail')
    level2 = models.ForeignKey('Level2Detail')
    level3 = models.ForeignKey('Level3Detail')
    level4 = models.ForeignKey('Level4Detail')
    level5 = models.ForeignKey('Level5Detail')
    level6 = models.ForeignKey('Level6Detail')
    level7 = models.ForeignKey('Level7Detail')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'device_level_mapping'
```

When I fire a query `DeviceLevelMapping.objects.filter(level1_id = l_id)` it says `unknown column`DeviceLevelMapping.id`.

Where is problem lying?

**EDITED**

```
class Level1Detail(models.Model):
    level1_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    level1_name = models.CharField(max_length=256L)
    organization = models.ForeignKey('OrganizationDetails')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'level1_detail'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many people pointed out, `level1_id` should be `level1__id`, but that will not raise a unknown columnDeviceLevelMapping.id` error.

Based on the structure of models and the `db_table` definition, I guess the db table is not created by Django syncdb, it is migrated from a existing project, and that table does not have a primary key.

Django models have [automatic primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), and the default field name is 'id'

The simplest solution: alter table device_level_mapping, add a column named id.

Comment: But that id will not be required anywhere. Is it a correct way to approach a problem. ?

Comment: The primary key is usedy by django orm everywhere at backends.

Comment: Ok. I'll just create an id for it. and will come back to you if I get any errors. Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide your suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870603/django-content-type-table-auth-permission

Answer (score 4):

To follow relationship in query use `__` (double underscore).

From your update the `id` field is `level1_id`, so query should be changed to

```
DeviceLevelMapping.objects.filter(level1__level1_id = l_id)
```

Comment: Now it says `Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are some xyz`. What is wrong now?

Comment: @user1162512, Have you changed `Level1Detail` to not have `id` field? Show us code for that model as well.

Comment: have you even read OP's error message before jumping to the conclusion

Comment: @Rohan - Level1Detail code is now shown in the edited question. Please check

Comment: @Leonardo.Z - What OP

Comment: Now, again the same error is being popped up. `unknown column DeviceLevelMapping.id`

Comment: @user1162512 are your db tables created by django syncdb or migrate? If not, check my answer and confirm your db table has a column named id

Comment: I initially created a db table and then t was migrated with `inspectdb` command. `If not, check my answer and confirm your db table has a column named id`. Column named id .Under which table are you talking of?

Comment: @user1162512 device_level_mapping

Comment: @Rohan - Can you please provide your suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870603/django-content-type-table-auth-permission

Answer (score 0):

You're querying for a ForeignKey so to traverse the relationship it's double underscores (or dunders) `__`

Change your query to

```
DeviceLevelMapping.objects.filter(level1__id = l_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like :

```
DeviceLevelMapping.objects.filter(level1__level1_id = l_id)
```

Comment: It says `DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'device_level_mapping.id' in 'field list'")`

Comment: Yes it is because of there is column of name id into device_level_mapping table. You can add manually into db or you can use south else simply just drop table and run syncdb .

Comment: you can follow as per @Leonardo